# NextGEN Gallery- using shortcode for different galleries on different pages

Tags: plugins, images, shortcode, gallery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [conditional shortcode not working](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64808/conditional-shortcode-not-working)

I have a [salon website](http://parlourdc.com/wp) with a gallery page wherein the user must first select a stylist prior to viewing their individual gallery.

I planned on using NextGen to house the images in stylist specific galleries, and using the NextGen shortcodes on each stylists page.
However, this doesn't seem to be working. For example, when viewing [Rebecca's page](http://parlourdc.com/wp/rebecca-h), the gallery doesn't show despite having the shortcode in the WP Page content field.

Any ideas what could be causing the problem?

The only solution I can come up with is to create a different page template for each stylist and utilize the shortcode there, but surely there is a better route to take?

relevant from gallery.php:

```
<div class="content">
                <h2>PARLOUR GALLERY</h2>
                <div id="stylist-list">
                        <h3><a href="index.php?page_id=29">REBECCA HAEHNLE</a> | <a href="index.php?page_id=31">CHRIS KELLER</a> | <a href="index.php?page_id=51">BILLY MALLOY</a> | <a href="index.php?page_id=35">VERONICA JONES</a> | <a href="index.php?page_id=39">ABBEY CASTELLANO</a> | <a href="index.php?page_id=53">QUARTIA FUTRELL</a> | <a href="index.php?page_id=43">ROOSEVELT OXENDINE</a> | <a href="index.php?page_id=45">NICOLE LUESCHOW</a> | <a href="index.php?page_id=47">MEREDITH NOWLIN</a> | <a href="index.php?page_id=49">MARICEL YALUNG</a> | <a href="index.php?page_id=33">STEPHANIE BRANDT</a></h3>
                </div><!-- end stylist-list -->
                <div class="gallery">
                            <?php  
                                    query_posts( 'tag=apples' );  
                                    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>  

                                    <?php endwhile; else: ?>  

                            <?php endif; ?>  
                </div><!-- end gallery -->
        </div><!-- end content -->
```

functions.php

```
<?php function nggallery( $shortcode ){ echo do_shortcode( $shortcode ); /* NextGen Gallery */ } ?>
```

**ETA** I am definitely open to alternative methods for having different galleries on different pages if there are any. Insight is welcomed!